# Events won't enter into the calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

```
displayEventTime: true,// Display event time
```

I don't know why `events[]` won't enter into calendar.
If I do this: `alert(${schedule.size())`
I can get size of `arrayList` that I got it from db. 
Also, same way, I can get title and start date.

`alert(${schedule.get(1).title)` - like this.

But if I put it inside of `for(){}`, it only appear first title and startdate.
Why?

Please, help me.

```
events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { 

    for(var i=0; i<'${schedule.size()}'; i++){
        events =[        
            {
                title  : '${schedule.get(i).title}',
                 start  : '${schedule.get(i).start_date.substring(0,10)}'
            }
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to input PHP variables in the javascript code?

Comment: No ,. I'm using Spring. and get List<Schedule> from db in Controller. and want to use that list in calender. I think variable i  dosen't work..

Comment: if anyone knows how to print list from server to print in calendar...let me know..